# In opencv-python cap.read() returns false after 1 second

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-3.7

I'm trying to label a video with opencv version 4.2.0.32, python 3.7.4 and win10. I installed opencv with pip. After I select a video from QFileDialog at first cap.read return with frame but after 15-16 frames cap.read return false and output video is only first 1 second of the main video. Help pls.

```
while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    ""some codes here""
    out.write(frame)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you post the ""some codes here"" or do a summary.

Comment: hey @SSR I actually solve the problem. It was code independent. It looks like opencv dlls were missing from the python path. I pasted the dlls and problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually solve the problem. It was code independent. It looks like opencv dlls were missing from the python path. I pasted the dlls and problem solved.

Comment: Can you elaborate, which dlls were missing where?

Comment: If dlls were missing how it managed to retrieve 15 frames?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't remember.